# Window.open location =no does not work

Tags: javascript

I need to create a popup in my web app to load a unity file. For that I'm using Javascript's Window.Open.

I don't want the user to see the popup's URL or to give him the chance to alter the URL.

According to this link:

http://javascript.about.com/library/blpopup10.htm

> "location can be set to yes or no to
>   indicate whether or not the new window
>   should display the location or address
>   bar. Note that this is a
>   recommendation only as some browsers
>   such as Firefox can disable this to
>   ensure that the toolbar will always
>   appear. In IE7 this setting controls
>   whether or not the navigation bar will
>   be displayed as the address bar will
>   always display in that browser. "

There is no longer a chance for me to remove the location from IE7.
I've tried to set it to location =no (and =0) and in fact it doesn't work in IE7/8 or Firefox. It does in Safari.

Since we all have had those boring spam popups that don't have the URL bar (called Location bar) that's a proof that there must be a way!
Hope that someone has the right answer.

Thank you.

Regards,
Bruno.

Comment: Can you show me an example of "those boring spam popups" that still has no address bar? That was a few years ago now. Browsers change.

Comment: thank you for your anwser. I could've show you a week ago in a friends blog. But after removing the web counter the pop up dissapeared. But I can assure you that It had no Location Bar.

Comment: OK, maybe you are right. Even if it was, it's pretty bad form to do this now. The user should always be aware of where their browser is pointing, and trends in browser design reflect this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

what about inline pop-ups? You can write your own code or see this: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog.

I dont use standard `window.open` javascript function at all, as in IE 8 it's IMHO impossible to hide location bar.

Inline (I mean html) dialogs have more features than `window.open`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to check that out. Cheers.

Comment: As suggested, if you can embed your unity file in a lightbox type "pop-over", that would be better. I imagine embedding is probably similar to Flash, so there's probably a fair bit of prior art out there.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to get rid of that bar in IE7 - this change was brought in as a security measure to help combat phishing.

As Feryt says, you can use inline popups, which is probably a better solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `window.open()` use `window.showModalDialog()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chromium Application Mode which works on all browsers expect Safari and Firefox.
I don't know the exact commands/paths for linux and mac, but you can search a bit.
run this code on cmd

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application" 
chrome.exe --app=https://yoursitehere.extension
```

or

Create a shortcut:
"C:\Program Files\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=https://yoursitehere.extension

For other browsers change the chrome location with the browsers' location.

By the way, this feature can be removed because of the security vulnerabilities.