# How to hide url in the popup window opened using window.open

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using below code to open a popup window in my page:

```
window.open("myPopupWindow.html", "_blank", "height=400, width=550, status=yes, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no, addressbar=no, top=200, left=300");
```

Although the url is disabled but even then it can be seen and copied. I have already set addressbar to no. How can I hide url in popup window?

Comment: the option is: location=no but this is only supported in some browsers. if you want to achieve something without showing the adress you can look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542721/window-open-location-no-does-not-work

Comment: it really depends on your browser. should be `location=no`. but most of the latest browsers disable hiding the location bar.

Comment: @Mordalthunder - okay, is there no any other option?

Comment: Window.open is very limited, so you have to use something like Javascript to simulate a dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just trying to mask the address, to make it look nicer or hide the fact that you're linking to to another website, or is it that you don't want people to know they can access that page without using your popup?

If it's the former, then what you could do is make the page you open in window.open an iframe, and point the iframe to your actual page.  They user could still access the target page, but only via your nicer looking url.

The other option is to use something like a colorbox with an iframe instead of window.open, which will mask the address. Have a look at the [Outside Webpage (iframe) example on this page](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example5/).

Of course whichever option you choose, someone smart can still track down the target url via the source code and go there directly.

Comment: I am concerned with your 3rd option. I don't want people copy my popup url and directly open it in the browser.

Comment: If you want to secure the page in such a way that even technical users can't access that page directly, but only via the popup, then you need server side technology like php to secure the file.  No way to do this with a straight .html page.

Comment: Okay, I am implementing all the security checks in my php fle now.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.open('http://mysite/proxy.html')
```

and in proxy.html :

```
  <html>
       <body> 
          <iframe src="/realPage.html"></iframe>
       </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: this does not hide address in pop-up open windows as requested by user

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution open new tab after that add url to `location.href`.

```
window.open('','_blank').location.href = "url"
```