# How to set title to iExplorer popup?

Tags: popup, internet-explorer-11, title

I am using following code to open new popup.

```
 var sFeatures =  'toolbar=0, directories=0, location=0, menubar=0, status=0, titlebar=0, scrollbars=0, resizable=0'+ ', width=' + screen.availWidth + ', height=' + (screen.availHeight - 40);

var newWin = window.open(url, '_blank', sFeatures, true);
```

There is a problem with popup title. Before page is loaded url is shown instead of title. When page is loaded title is set. I need to change title before the page is loaded. I tried following code but it doesn't work:

```
newWin.document.title = 'Anything';
```

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using? You could also try to use

```
newWin.onload = function () { this.document.title = "Anything"; }
```

But I think you can't change the title before the page is loaded. `onload` also waits for everything to be loaded. The actual title comes from the `<title>` element and if the page is not fully loaded then you can't oprate on the element.

Comment: I'm using internet explorer. This is not working. I tried with chrome and it works there, but I need to make it work on iExplorer. I tried to set title like this:
`newWin.document.write('<title>Report</title>')`
it works for title, but url is not loading.
Can I at least hide url that is showing instead of title?

Comment: You could put the page you want to open in an `iframe` or use some plugins like [Colorbox](https://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) instead of `window.open` to hide the url. For more information, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982105/how-to-hide-url-in-the-popup-window-opened-using-window-open).